# Querying EXISTS in many to many relations in Criteria API

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Having two entity classes with a many to many relation, I am trying to create query which tests the existence of any relationship for all entities from one table. I am stuck because it seems that there is no way to refer to the JoinTable through the Criteria API.

Example entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="man")
public class Man  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="woman")
public class Woman  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="man_woman",
            joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="woman_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="man_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    private Set<Man> men;
}
```

I would like to create a query using criteria API which would result in SQL such as:

```
select m.id, 
       case when exists(select * from man_woman mw where mw.man_id=m.id) then 1 else 0
from man;
```

The best I have come up with so far is the following:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

Root<Man> from = criteriaQuery.from(Man.class);

Subquery<Long> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Long.class);

Root<Woman> sub_from = subquery.from(Woman.class);  
SetJoin<Woman, Man> setJoin = sub_from.join(Woman_.men);
subquery.select(sub_from.get(Woman_.id));
subquery.where(from.in(setJoin.get(Man_.id)));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(from.alias("man_entity"),
        criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                .when(
                        criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery)
                        , true)
                .otherwise(false)
                .alias("knows_any_women")
);

return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList()
```

which results in SQL containing extra joins:

```
select m.id, 
       case when exists(select w.id 
                        from woman w 
                            inner join man_woman mw on w.id = mw.woman_id
                            inner join man m2 on m2.id = mw.man_id
                        where m.id in (m2.id)
                        ) 
            then 1 else 0
from man;
```

I guess this statement would eventually be optimized to look like my desired one - but is there a way to make it simpler from the beginning?

Comment: have a class `Relation`? then you can select the "join" table, and are able to add extra attributes to it if required ...

Comment: Great idea, thanks! Although if this scenario appears in multiple situations in the application, I would soon be cluttered with plenty of those Relation classes. Therefore it would be more convenient if there was a way to do it through the query.